# how to zip lists into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, zip

i have 6 lists all of equal length but when i zip them into a dictionary, the length of the dictionary is not equal to the length of the lists. Is my code wrong?

```
    print len(v)
    print len(t)
    print len(c)
    print len(s)
    print len(o)
    print len(v)

output: 
79
79
79
79
79
79
   mydict[country] = dict(zip(v,zip(t,c,s,o,v)))

print len(mydict[country])

output:
22
```

Comment: Are there duplicate items in `v`?

Comment: You might have duplicate items which are discarded , be sure by printing `len(list(zip(v,zip(t,c,s,o,v))))`

Comment: hm yes to the output of the above gives me `22` which is the same as `len(mydict[country])`

Comment: Start with a smaller example that illustrates the issue.  What is the data, and what is your expected result?  You are trying to create a dictionary keyed off of country, but where is the source of the key and what is the dictionary expected to hold.

Comment: is there a quick way to replace all the values in `list v` with unique values?

Comment: You're only allowed one unique key, so if `v` has duplicates, each one is overwritten by the new item.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander for the quick manipulation. it works! if you want to post the answer anyway i can give you a tick